# How to use tryCatch when the outcome is not distinct

Tags: r, function, error-handling, try-catch

I have a function that I have made which returns a dataframe with two variables. As a simple example lets have:

```
test <- function(x) {y <- matrix( 5 , nrow= x , ncol =  2)
                    z<- data.frame(y) 
                    return(z) }
```

I want to find out on which x values this function gives an error. (on our example I think for negative values, but I just want to convey the concept.) So I try:

```
z <- rep(0)
testnumbers <- c(0,1,2,3,4,-1,5)

for (i in 1:length(testnumbers)) {

  tempo <- tryCatch( testfun(testnumbers[i]) , error= function(e) return(0) )

  if (tempo == 0 )  z[i] <- {testnumbers[i] next}

}
```

What is wrong with my process and how can I find where in my function does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to run *all* of the `testnumbers` regardless of any of them failing, I suggest a slightly different tact.

### Base R

This borrows from Rui's use of `inherits` which is more robust and unambiguous. It goes one step further by preserving not just which one had the error, but the actual error text as well:

```
testfun <- function(x) {
    y <- matrix(5, nrow = x, ncol = 2)
    z <- as.data.frame(y)
    z
}
testnumbers <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5)

rets <- setNames(
  lapply(testnumbers, function(n) tryCatch(testfun(n), error=function(e) e)),
  testnumbers
)

sapply(rets, inherits, "error")
#     0     1     2     3     4    -1     5 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
Filter(function(a) inherits(a, "error"), rets)
# $`-1`
# <simpleError in matrix(5, nrow = x, ncol = 2): invalid 'nrow' value (< 0)>
```

(The `setNames(lapply(...), ...)` is because the inputs are numbers so `sapply(..., simplify=F)` did not preserve the names, something I thought was important.)

All of this falls in line with what some consider good practice: if you're doing one function to a lot of "things", then do it in a `list`, and therefore in one of the `*apply` functions.

### `tidyverse`

There is a function in `purrr` that formalizes this a little: `safely`, which returns a function wrapped around its argument. For instance:

```
library(purrr)
safely(testfun)
# function (...) 
# capture_error(.f(...), otherwise, quiet)
# <environment: 0x0000000015151d90>
```

It is returning a function that can then be passed. A one-time call would look like one of the following:

```
safely(testfun)(0)
# $result
# [1] V1 V2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# $error
# NULL
testfun_safe <- safely(testfun)
testfun_safe(0)
# $result
# [1] V1 V2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# $error
# NULL
```

To use it here, you can do:

```
rets <- setNames(
  lapply(testnumbers, safely(testfun)),
  testnumbers
)
str(rets[5:6])
# List of 2
#  $ 4 :List of 2
#   ..$ result:'data.frame':    4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ V1: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
#   .. ..$ V2: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
#   ..$ error : NULL
#  $ -1:List of 2
#   ..$ result: NULL
#   ..$ error :List of 2
#   .. ..$ message: chr "invalid 'nrow' value (< 0)"
#   .. ..$ call   : language matrix(5, nrow = x, ncol = 2)
#   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
Filter(Negate(is.null), sapply(rets, `[[`, "error"))
# $`-1`
# <simpleError in matrix(5, nrow = x, ncol = 2): invalid 'nrow' value (< 0)>
```

and to get to the results of all runs (including the errant one):

```
str(sapply(rets, `[[`, "result"))
# List of 7
#  $ 0 :'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num(0) 
#   ..$ V2: num(0) 
#  $ 1 :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num 5
#   ..$ V2: num 5
#  $ 2 :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:2] 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:2] 5 5
#  $ 3 :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:3] 5 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:3] 5 5 5
#  $ 4 :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
#  $ -1: NULL
#  $ 5 :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:5] 5 5 5 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:5] 5 5 5 5 5
```

or just the results without the failed run:

```
str(Filter(Negate(is.null), sapply(rets, `[[`, "result")))
# List of 6
#  $ 0:'data.frame':    0 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num(0) 
#   ..$ V2: num(0) 
#  $ 1:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num 5
#   ..$ V2: num 5
#  $ 2:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:2] 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:2] 5 5
#  $ 3:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:3] 5 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:3] 5 5 5
#  $ 4:'data.frame':    4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
#  $ 5:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:5] 5 5 5 5 5
#   ..$ V2: num [1:5] 5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You were actually quite close. I'm not sure what did the trick in the end but I

1. Changed the 1:length(testnumbers) as this is unneccessary
2. Changed `return(0)` to a character
3. Wrapped your if in another if as it kept failing if the length was larger than 1 or could not be assessed.

Then you get the correct results. You could try and change the code bit by bit to see what was wrong.

```
test <- function(x) {y <- matrix( 5 , nrow = x , ncol =  2)
z<- data.frame(y) 
return(z) }

errored <- numeric()
testnumbers <- c(0,1,2,3,4,-1,5)

for (i in testnumbers) {      
  tempo <- tryCatch(test(i), error = function(e) "error")      
  if (length(tempo) == 1) {
    if (tempo == "error")  errored <- c(errored, i)
  }      
}
errored
> -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `tryCatch` to return the error, not zero.

```
testfun <- function(x) {
    y <- matrix(5, nrow = x, ncol = 2)
    z <- as.data.frame(y)
    z
}

testnumbers <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5)
z <- numeric(length(testnumbers))

for (i in seq_along(testnumbers)) {
    tempo <- tryCatch(testfun(testnumbers[i]), error = function(e) e)
    if (inherits(tempo, "error")) {
        z[i] <- testnumbers[i]
    }
}

z
#[1]  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0
```

Also,

- In order to coerce a `matrix` to `data.frame` use `as.data.frame`.
- I have removed the calls to `return` since the last value of a function is its return value.
- `rep(0)` is the same as just `0`, replaced by `numeric(length(testnumbers))`.
- `seq_along(testnumbers)` is always better than `1:length(testnumbers)`. Try it with `testnumbers` of length zero and see what happens.